# Is there a way to uninstall last bower update?

Tags: angularjs, bower, angular-material

I updated bower using the command

> bower update

Since my update I am having issues with angular-material. I highly suspect this is because of the update that resulted in incompatibilities.

Now, I want to rollback the changes that update has made. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: restore previous bower.json, and run again?

Comment: How do I get the previous copy of bower.json?

Comment: you dont have version management tools like git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason i got a lot of issues when i update angular-material to the lastest stable version (1.0.7).

So, just as a workaround, you can set manually the version is working right:

In bower.json replace this:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular-material": "1.1.0-rc2",
...
}
```

Comment: I will have to run `bower install` after making these changes to bower.json, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but be aware of change the version when angular material 1.1.x become stable.